# Conditional dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

On Gradle (more specifically with Android) how can I have conditional dependency so that they get loaded either from the parent project like this:

```
compile project(':lib')
```

or from a repository is not present in the parent project:

```
compile 'com.sample:lib:+'
```

one possible solution I thought of is to do this:

```
compile allprojects.find({ it.name.equal('lib')}) != null  ? project(':lib') : 'com.sample:lib:+'
```

but the allProjects property is not available in the dependencies task.

**Update:**

The reason I'm searching for this because we have two setups, one with our sub-projects imported from different git repositories at the development machines and the second one importing the dependencies from our dependencies server for CI.

An alternative I've tried is to set this in the parent project:

```
ext.projectNames = allprojects.collect{ it.name }
```

and in the subproject I'm doing this:

```
compile projectNames.contains('lib') ? project(':lib') : 'com.sample:lib:+'
```

This works, but however since in the current setup we run just one of the subproject in the CI server this property won't exist and will fail so may have to extract this behaviour to a plugin and maybe play with getParent()

Comment: Why do you want the dependencies to be conditional, resolved at build file evaluation time? Can you be much more detailed about what you're trying to do? There has to be a better solution.

Comment: Asking 'why?' when someone asks 'who?' is kind of avoiding the question altogether. I want to know how to cook beans not what could I do if I had chickpeas ;) But I've updated the question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I had a need for the same feature. Getting it to work with gradle was a cinch. The hard part was figuring out how Android Studio syncs the gradle files. Without a successful sync, the IDE will complain it can't find any dependencies. At any rate, I figured it out, here is my solution to make it work with gradle and Android Studio.

https://gist.github.com/vangorra/c1383c355ce8fe56adf8

It essentially boils down to defining the project in settings.gradle:

```
include 'library'
project(':library').projectDir = file('../Library/library')
```

Then you have to use a one-liner with options closure for your dependency:

```
compile ( project(':library').projectDir.exists() ? project(':library'): 'Library:library:unspecified@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: That's promising! Is it still valid or is there an better solution? It has been almost 2 years since your answer. I wan't to introduce nightly jenkins build / naxeus for my Android project.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically resolving to either project dependency or external dependency isn't yet a first-class Gradle feature, and it takes some effort (and may incur some limitations) to implement it in a build. You can find a proof-of-concept here: https://github.com/pniederw/elastic-deps

PS: It's `allprojects`, not `allProjects`.

Comment: Great proposal. I've tried something along does lines. But I encounter the problem I commented on my question.

Comment: You'll have to take the current context into account, like elastic-deps does.